# java: Split period of time in single years

Tags: java, date

i have two dates in java. One date is the start date, the second the finish date. Plz see my code:

```
LocalDate startdate = LocalDate.parse("2022-12-01");
LocalDate finishdate = LocalDate.parse("2024-10-05");
```

I like to split this period into the single years. For example

```
p1 = 2022-12-01 ... 2022-12-31
p2 = 2023-01-01 ... 2023-12-31
P3 = 2024-01-01 ... 2024-10-05
```

But how can i loop throug the years? And check?

Comment: Use `LocalDate#getYear` on both and loop over it. Then create new dates with those years and maybe use `Period` to create those ranges. Its a bit unclear what exactly ur facing trouble with.

Comment: @Zabuzard `getYear()` is a perfect suggestion.  I haven't seen what we want the `Period` class for (you did say *maybe*).

Comment: [My suggestions here](https://rextester.com/NGRJ77329)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach for this might be working with `TemporalAdjusters[1]`
Of course, there are plenty of other approaches as well ;)

Assume we create the following value object:

```
class Period{
    final LocalDate begin;
    final LocalDate end;

    Period(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end) {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s - %s", begin, end);
    }
}
```

The (in this case recursive) logic might be as follows - starting with a startdate, finishdate, and an empty list - add periods as long as the finishdate is after the last periods end:

```
List<Period> periods(LocalDate startdate, LocalDate finishdate, List<Period> periodsList){
        final LocalDate periodEnd = startdate.with(lastDayOfYear());
        if(periodEnd.isBefore(finishdate)){
            periodsList.add(new Period(startdate, periodEnd));
            return periods(periodEnd.plusDays(1), finishdate, periodsList);
        }
        periodsList.add(new Period(finishdate.with(firstDayOfYear()), finishdate));
        return periodsList;
    }
```

A complete working example with a simple main might look like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.firstDayOfYear;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfYear;

public class Periods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final LocalDate startdate = LocalDate.parse("2022-12-01");
        final LocalDate finishdate = LocalDate.parse("2024-10-05");

        periods(startdate, finishdate).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static List<Period> periods(LocalDate startdate, LocalDate finishdate){
        return periods(startdate, finishdate, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    private static List<Period> periods(LocalDate startdate, LocalDate finishdate, List<Period> periodsList){
        final LocalDate periodEnd = startdate.with(lastDayOfYear());
        if(periodEnd.isBefore(finishdate)){
            periodsList.add(new Period(startdate, periodEnd));
            return periods(periodEnd.plusDays(1), finishdate, periodsList);
        }
        periodsList.add(new Period(finishdate.with(firstDayOfYear()), finishdate));
        return periodsList;
    }

}

class Period{
    final LocalDate begin;
    final LocalDate end;

    Period(LocalDate begin, LocalDate end) {
        this.begin = begin;
        this.end = end;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s - %s", begin, end);
    }
}
```

As pointed out in the comments Java provides a `Period[2]` class which can be used as well. For the reason of simplicity - printing start and end - here a simple bean class is introduced.

Comment: You do not have to reinvent the wheel. `Period` already exists.

Comment: I absolutely agree. For the reason of simplicity to only provide what is necessary regarding the question I provided the simple class. I will add a note to the answer.

Comment: @Zabuzard The existing `Period` class is different from the one used here in that it neither holds a start nor an end date. It is just a length of time. It therefore will not work for the requirements we have here.